# Depth Pass for Particles in Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, depth-of-field, depth-map

Can't find much information on this but I have tried using the Depth > Normalize > ColorRamp to control depth pass for particles but doesnt seem to work. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Would you mind telling me what is the meaning of Depth Pass, I might be able to help you then.

Comment: If you are using Render as Object it should be fine ... Or you can try Mist pass since Z pass is not antialiased https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/passes.html but I saw few days ago Compositor has a new Antialiasing node ...